# Read object at runtime and render fields according to that in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm working on creating a React component for a filterable table, and I'm running into the issue of making it modular enough to accept two props and render the table and data properly. The problem is that I don't know what, and how many, columns and rows will be passed to this component, so how do I render it dynamically?

The current solution that I'm working on is using `Object.entries()` to pull out the key value pairs that will be provided as `props` to the component. I know how to render these out properly (using the `map` function and returning JSX with the data pulled out from each element). My question is **how do I run a particular function for specific columns dynamically**.  For eg, the following code is what I have for now:

```
columnOnClick = (e) => {
console.log(`The value captured from column header click is: 
${e.target.value}`);

switch(e.target.value) {
  case 'Item # Item1 Item2 Item3':
    console.log(`Item column was run!`);
    break;
  case 'Type':
  case 'Special':
  case 'Not Special':
    console.log(`Type column was run!`);
    break;
  case 'In Stock':
  case 'Y':
  case 'N':
    console.log(`In stock column was run!`);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`This will NEVER be run!`);
 }
}
```

And my render method looks like:

```
        <th>
          <div className="select">
            <select onChange={this.columnOnClick}>
              <option>In stock</option>
              <option>Y</option>
              <option>N</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {
        this.state.visibleTable.map((row, rowIndex) => {
          return (
            <tr key={rowIndex+1}>
              <td>{row.item}</td>
              <td>{row.type}</td>
              <td>{row.inStock}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      }
    </tbody>
```

So `onClickColumn` will get called every time a select option is clicked. The problem is that because it's dynamic (i.e. I don't know how many columns there are) this is the only method that will be attached to `n` number of columns that are generated dynamically. This means the only thing I have to work with is `e.target.value`. I'm planning on reading that value and create a switch statement which filters out data according to the value for a particular table and store it as a JSON object with array of objects (i.e. rows) to be rendered.

**If I don't have any idea of what the columns are named, how do I create `cases` for those at runtime? Can I do something similar to create an array of strings and give that as one case in the switch statement?**

Comment: @trixn If I'm understanding correctly, you're suggesting `{col1: (e.target.value)=>{//something}, col2: (e.target.value)=>{//something}}`. Assuming that I'm heading in the right direction, does this need to happen for *all* the filters in all the columns?

Comment: I didn't really get where you take the options of your select from.

Comment: @trixn They will be taken from the props, but in the example above I'm hardcoding them in for now

Comment: Sorry but after reading your question the third time i'm still confused. What do you want to filter, how should the table look like? Do you want to render a select for each table head and filter in that column? Please add the complete component code to your question so we get a more complete picture.